# Drawing and retain the changes on HTML5 canvas

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, pinchzoom

I should be able to draw on the picture and save it. I was wondering if there is possibility to allow users to draw over the map(shape) only?
Here is the complate code:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYOXRW

```
var ctx, color = '#FF0000';
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
setTimeout(function() {
    newCanvas();
}, 1000);
}, false);
 function newCanvas() {
document.getElementById("content").style.height = window.innerHeight + 100;
var canvas = '<canvas id="canvas" width="' + window.innerWidth + '" height="' + (window.innerHeight + 50) + '"></canvas>';
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = canvas;
ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.strokeStyle = color;
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-_laBnztzAG8/Ub7mDK4Z3qI/AAAAAAAABu4/LBPUeAVeJcc/s1600/CA+KATHMANDU+VALLEY_HU.png';
image.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var iWidth = image.width / 3;
    var iHeight = image.height / 3;
    ctx.drawImage(image, (canvas.width - iWidth) / 2, (canvas.height - iHeight) / 2, iWidth, iHeight);
};
drawTouch();
drawMouse();
}
 function selectColor(el) {
color = window.getComputedStyle(el).color;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = color;
}
 var drawTouch = function() {
var start = function(e) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    x = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
    y = e.changedTouches[0].pageY;
    ctx.moveTo(x, y);
};
var move = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    x = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
    y = e.changedTouches[0].pageY;
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    ctx.stroke();
};
document.getElementById("canvas").addEventListener("touchstart", start, false);
document.getElementById("canvas").addEventListener("touchmove", move, false);
 };
var drawMouse = function() {
var clicked = 0;
var start = function(e) {
    clicked = 1;
    ctx.beginPath();
    x = e.pageX;
    y = e.pageY;
    ctx.moveTo(x, y);
};
var move = function(e) {
    if (clicked) {
        x = e.pageX;
        y = e.pageY;
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
};
var stop = function(e) {
    clicked = 0;
};
document.getElementById("canvas").addEventListener("mousedown", start, false);
document.getElementById("canvas").addEventListener("mousemove", move, false);
document.addEventListener("mouseup", stop, false);
};
 function saveBtn() {
console.log(document.getElementById('canvas').toDataURL());
}
```

Comment: Please don't ask two questions in one. When you have two unrelated questions, please ask them separately. This is also good for you, because that way you won't only get answers from people who can answer both questions. I took the freedom to remove that question I couldn't answer well. You can retrieve the text I removed from the edit history and post it as a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want the user to be able to draw on an image in a non-destructive way, you can create a second canvas and use CSS positioning to place it on top of the first canvas. The user can now draw freely on the canvas above while the canvas below is unaffected and still visible through any alpha-transparent areas (by the way, when you don't intend to do any canvas-operations at all on the background, you can just as well use a plain old `<img>`).

When you would like to turn both canvases into one image which you can save, create a new off-screen canvas and draw both canvases to it with `drawImage` (yes, drawImage can use a `<canvas>` as a source, just as it can take an `<img>`). You can then use [`canvas.toDataURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) to get a PNG or JPEG compressed and base64-encoded string of the canvas content. You can then store that string however you want.